# problema com jogo em Prolog usando Matriz numérica

Tags: prolog, sublime-text-3

Eu estou fazendo um "jogo" no Prolog, a partir de uma posição inicial em uma matriz, o jogo deve retornar todos os caminhos possíveis, onde toda a matriz é -1 e a posição atual é definida como 0. Deve escrever todas as rotas possíveis em um arquivo .txt

Estou editando por sublime, compilando usando SWI-Prolog.

```
inicia(X,Y,Matriz,Caminho) :- jogar(Matriz,X,Y,Caminho), escreveArq(Caminho).
```

Imprime a matriz atual do jogo

```
imprimeMatriz([]).
imprimeMatriz([H|T]) :- imprimeLista(H),nl, imprimeMatriz(T).
imprimeLista([]).
imprimeLista([H|T]) :- write(H),  write(", "), imprimeLista(T).
```

Escreve no arquivo

```
escreveArq([]).
escreveArq(Rota) :- open('caminho.txt', write, ID), writeq(ID,Rota), write(ID,'\n'), close(ID).
```

Recupera elemento da lista

```
recuperaElemento(X, Y, Elemento,Matriz) :- achaElemento(X,0,Matriz,ListaX), achaElemento(Y,0,ListaX,Elemento).
```

Acha um elemento.

```
achaElemento(_,_,[],_) :- false.
achaElemento(Elemento,Aux,[H|_],H) :- Elemento == Aux.
achaElemento(Elemento,Aux,[_|HT],R) :- Aux1 is Aux + 1, achaElemento(Elemento,Aux1,HT,R).
```

Descobre vizinhos de (X,Y)

```
elementoSuperior(X,Y,Elemento,Matriz) :- N is X-1, recuperaElemento(N,Y,Elemento, Matriz).
elementoSuperior(_,_,-5,_).
elementoInferior(X,Y,Elemento,Matriz) :- N is X+1, recuperaElemento(N,Y,Elemento,Matriz).
elementoInferior(_,_,-5,_).
elementoDireita(X,Y,Elemento,Matriz) :- N is Y+1, recuperaElemento(X,N,Elemento,Matriz).
elementoDireita(_,_,-5,_).
elementoEsquerda(X,Y,Elemento,Matriz) :- N is Y-1, recuperaElemento(X,N,Elemento,Matriz).
elementoEsquerda(_,_,-5,_).
```

Verifica se jogo chegou ao fim

```
fimDeJogo(Matriz) :- verificaFim(Matriz,R), R == 1.
    verificaFim([],X) :- X is 0.
    verificaFim([H|T],X) :- verificaFimColuna(H,X1), verificaFim(T,X2), X is X1 + X2.
    verificaFimColuna([],X) :- X is 0, !.
    verificaFimColuna([H|T],R) :- H == -1, verificaFimColuna(T, R).
    verificaFimColuna([H|T],X) :- H == 0, verificaFimColuna(T, R), X is R+1.
```

Jogo em si

```
jogar(Matriz, _,_,_) :- fimDeJogo(Matriz).
jogar(Matriz, X,Y,["S"|Rota]) :- elementoSuperior(X,Y,Z,Matriz),Z > -1,decrementa(X,Y,Matriz,NMAtriz),
                                                                                        NX is X-1,jogar(NMAtriz, NX, Y,Rota).
jogar(Matriz, X,Y,["I"|Rota]) :- elementoInferior(X,Y,Z,Matriz),Z > -1,decrementa(X,Y,Matriz,NMAtriz),
                                                                                        NX is X+1,jogar(NMAtriz, NX, Y,Rota).
jogar(Matriz, X,Y,["E"|Rota]) :- elementoEsquerda(X,Y,Z,Matriz),Z > -1,decrementa(X,Y,Matriz,NMAtriz),
                                                                                        NY is Y-1,jogar(NMAtriz, X, NY,Rota).
jogar(Matriz, X,Y,["D"|Rota]) :- elementoDireita(X,Y,Z,Matriz) ,Z > -1,decrementa(X,Y,Matriz,NMAtriz),
                                                                                        NY is Y+1,jogar(NMAtriz, X, NY,Rota).
```

Muda numero em (X,Y)

```
decrementa(X,Y,Matriz, MatrizAtualizada) :- reduzX(X,Y,0,0,Matriz,MatrizAtualizada).
    reduzX(_,_,    _,    _,    [],         []) .
    reduzX(X,Y,    X, AuxY, [H|T], [LAlt|Mat]) :- NX is X+1,reduzY(X,Y, AuxY,  AuxY, H, LAlt), reduzX(X,Y,NX, AuxY, T, Mat).
    reduzX(X,Y, AuxX, AuxY, [H|T], [   H|Mat]) :- NAuxX is AuxX+1, reduzX(X,Y,NAuxX, AuxY, T,  Mat).
        reduzY(_,_, _,    _,    [],       []) .
        reduzY(_,Y, _,    Y, [H|T], [NH|MAT]) :- NH is H-1, NY is Y+1,   reduzY(_,Y, _, NY, T, MAT).
        reduzY(_,Y, _, AuxY, [H|T], [ H|MAT]) :-           NY is AuxY+1, reduzY(_,Y, _, NY, T, MAT).
```

**Meu problema:**
para algumas matrizes, exemplo [[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]] gera um caminho errado e apresenta apenas um caminho.